# HTML shows on page after flash

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a successful flash notice for when users enter their email and a failure flash notice for when something goes wrong. Both function, but there's a little number under the notice. When I push to heroku, instead of just a number its the entire line of html code showing up under the flash -- `<div class='background'> <div class='alert alert-success'>Thanks for staying up to date.</div>`

The haml view:

```
%body
= if flash[:notice]
  .alert.alert-success= flash[:notice]
= if flash[:alert]
  .alert.alert-danger= flash[:alert]
```

The controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @lead.save
    format.html { redirect_to :back, :notice => 'Thanks for staying up to date.' }
  else
    format.html { redirect_to :back, :alert => 'Uh oh, there was a problem.'}
  end
end
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Op1h.png)

Thanks in advance~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `=` with `-`

Use `=` when you need to display / render the output in html view.

Use `-` when you just need to evaluate something or assigning something like that

```
%body
- if flash[:notice]
  .alert.alert-success= flash[:notice]
- if flash[:alert]
  .alert.alert-danger= flash[:alert]
```

Comment: `=` instead of `-` is true, but the question was about the "html code" wasn't it?

Comment: actually no if you see the output https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Op1h.png its printing it twice because of `=`

Comment: okay, i find the question poorly worded. ```Both function, but there's a little number under the notice. When I push to heroku, instead of just a number its the entire line of html code showing up under the flash```